# What does a +1 on an answer stand for?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I just had a +1 on an answer I had voted on:

[image: +1]

What does it stand for? Note that there's no link on the title (the *"Why using "this" keyword to get superclass methods"* part of the image), unlike a *classic reputation gain*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you downvote an answer, you get -1 reputation. I assume that the answer which you downvoted previously got deleted by the owner or a moderator. So as result you got your -1 reputation as +1 back.

Here is the deleted answer's screenshot,

> [image]

Comment: You're right, I remember now the answer I downvoted.

Comment: @sp00m - So your first sentence is wrong: *I just had a +1 on an answer **I gave***

Comment: ok, So when you will reach 10K+ reputation, you will be able to see who has deleted that answer. :)

Comment: @hims056 I also answered the said question, that's why I got confused.

Comment: @Lucifer Haha ok, "wait-and-see" :)

Answer (score 2):

A similar situation might arise if you hit the rep cap of 200 points from upvotes only. Say you have amassed a total of 199 rep for the day, then an additional upvote will only give you +1 rep, instead of the usual amount for your upvoted question/answer.

Comment: This is called Rep Cap and for the record you reached it only by Serial upvoting which was reversed. Anyway that's not the case here as you can see by reading the other answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd i face this problem so i reply.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd THEN why give -1

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh: Although that is also a possibility, it doesn't really answer the question, since the +1 comes from different source.

Comment: Please, *please* don't use "dear". In the English-speaking world, dear is a rather informal term used to describe someone you have some affections for.

Comment: Please also use capitalized "I"s when you write in English and **do not** use "u" or "r" (they're not words!).

Comment: This is definitely a viable answer for the question (as per title) even if it isn't the case for this specific user and instance.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh, +1 agree with you